# Find the volume inside a cylinder and outside a hyperboloid

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm trying to find the volume of $f(x,y,z)=y$ inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and outside the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$,
and I got the integral

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^y \int_1^\sqrt{1+z^2} rdrdzd\theta$

thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to change it in cylindrical coordinates, and I got stuck
$r^2=4, \Rightarrow 4-z^2=1, z=\sqrt 3$ 
$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_\sqrt 3^y \int_2^\sqrt{2-r^2}rdrdzd\theta$

Comment: There should be no $y$ anywhere in the limits. $y$ is not one of the cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: my mistake, then 
$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_?^? \int_2^\sqrt{2-r^2}$

Comment: **Integral** of the function. And you are forgetting the integrand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cylinder:
$$
x^2+y^2 = 4\implies r = 2.
$$
Hyperboloid:
$$
x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1\implies z^2 = r^2 - 1\implies
r = \sqrt{z^2 + 1}.
$$
Now, you need to find the intersection between cylinder and hyperboloid... Can you continue?